# Roboteq Driver Guidelines

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am new to ROS (just finished the beginner's tutorials and learnt about rosserial_arduino) and I am using a Roboteq BLDC motor controller for an autonomous car project. I already know that the microbasic script should be generated using the Roboteq PC utility. Could anyone please provide some guidelines on how to use the driver itself? I have Googled about it (maybe I am not entering the right keywords) and tried to look at Grizzly codes but still have no idea where to start (how to send commands to the controller and how to read its feedback). Are there any resources where I can learn about it?

Thank you,

Alena

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254917/roboteq-driver-guidelines/) by [alkaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/29389/alkaza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try running:

`roslaunch roboteq_driver example.launch`

That's as far as I've got myself.

---

Originally posted by [peteretep](https://answers.ros.org/users/33127/peteretep/) with karma: 26 on 2018-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0